# Facebook iOS SDK and Safari based authentication issue

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

I have used latest FB SKD in my iOS app so users can use facebook account to login. Application open the FB app and comes back to my app perfectly fine. However, in some place in the app, i have to show/pull some people facebook page (safari based using WebView), but even user already used the Facebook account to login into my native ios app, but the page still ask user to login again and when they click login, it shows them the annoying FB username/pass page. 
Is there anyway, that the FB safari based page can authenticate the user since it's already logged into my app using FB integration? do i have to include query or something. Please give me details how to solve this problem since i'm new in this..
thanks again for your help...

pic: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rjlptu7ufpcq3vl/fb.png

Answer (score 0):

When the user switches to Facebook app to authenticate, it doesn't create a cookie for your `UIWebView` which is why it's asking to login again. Have the user authenticate inside the UIWebView without switching to the Facebook app.

Comment: Thank you for reply. But i don't want user athenticate "again". they already did when they logged into the application. do you mean there is a way to create cookie for UIWebView and pass it to safari in the beginning using FB SDK? can u please give me more details?

Answer (score 0):

What you're talking about also sounds like a similar thing that happens with Facebook dialogs not knowing about the current Facebook session.

If you authenticate your user via Facebook, try saying the Facebook object itself as an instance variable somewhere in memory so you can access it again (a property on a singleton controller, perhaps?).

Spawning dialogs from an authenticated Facebook object appears to let them use the dialog without reauthenticating iff you have a [FBSession activeSession]. So you'd also have to maintain an active FB session. But I'm not sure if this kind of solution will work since you didn't show specific code for how you're doing your web-based FB fetches.

This question might also prove helpful:

[Implement Login with Facebook in iOS 5 and 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14271792/implement-login-with-facebook-in-ios-5-and-6)