# Implement Login with Facebook in iOS 5 and 6

Tags: ios, facebook

This question look duplicate and ye it is 50% duplicate because there is no good answer I found any where.

let me divide my question in three part.

***Current Situation:***
I have implemented sign up screen with Email, Date of birth, Gender and Zipcode.
This is working very nice. I have also implement share feature in facebook and twitter in iOS 5 and 6
 But now I want to implement it with facebook and twitter like 
shown in following example screen:

[image: Login With Facebook]

***What is problem:***
I want to know how can I implement login with facebook in iOS 5. twitter is integrated with ios 5 and 6, Facebook with iOS  6 so that is not big deal (right now I think so). I have already implemented share feature for both twitter and facebook for iOS 5 & 6. so what more I need to do to implement login.

***What I get in response:***
As I said I need Email, Date of birth, Gender and Zipcode at time of signup.
How can I get this information if I use login with facebook and twitter.
What should I do if user have not given or block this information of this social site.

Thanks.......

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how I implemented this feature in my app:

1. Download the Facebook SDK for iOS from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/ios/)
2. In your `AppDelegate.h` make a property of the Facebook object.

   ```
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
   #import "Facebook.h"

   @interface OutpearAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
       UIWindow *window;
       IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;        
   }

   @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;
   @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
   @property (nonatomic, retain) Facebook *facebook;
   +(DemoAppDelegate*)getAppDelegate;
   ```
3. In your `AppDelegate.m` write this:

   ```
   synthesize facebook;
   ```

   and in your `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method write this:

   ```
   // Initialize Facebook with app ID
   facebook=[[Facebook alloc]initWithAppId:FB_APP_KEY andDelegate:nil];
   //here FB_AP_Key is your Facebook application key
   ```

   and release `facebook` in `dealloc`
4. Where you want to login with Facebook write this function:

   ```
   - (void)loginWithFacbookIdClicked
   {
       [DemoAppDelegate getAppDelegate].facebook.sessionDelegate=self;

       if(isInternetAvailable)
       {
           if([[DemoAppDelegate getAppDelegate].facebook isSessionValid])
           {
               //[facebookIntegration getUserFacebookPersonalInfo];
                NSLog("User already logined with facebook");
           }
           else
           {
               [[DemoAppDelegate getAppDelegate].facebook authorize:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"read_stream",
                                    @"publish_stream",
                                    @"email",
                                    @"user_birthday",
                                    @"friends_about_me",
                                    @"friends_activities",
                                    @"friends_likes",
                                    nil]];
           }
       }
       else
       {
          NSLog("No Internet Connection");
       }       
   }
   ```
5. After login, the Facebook SDK delegate methods are automatically called. Do your stuff in delegate methods.

   ```
   - (void)fbDidLogin
   {
      NSLog("Logged into Facebook");
      // Your logic goes here.   
   }

   -(void)fbDidNotLogin:(BOOL)cancelled
   {
       DLog(@"Login Cancelled");
   }

   -(void)fbDidExtendToken:(NSString *)accessToken expiresAt:(NSDate *)expiresAt
   {

   }

   -(void)fbSessionInvalidated
   {

   }

   -(void)fbDidLogout
   {

   }
   ```

Comment: I am using your code for facebook sign up and for uploading status. Its working properly. Thanks for it. But now I want to like a feed through iOS app using your code. Can you give me some suggestions for it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to pull this [link](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) from github. It contains a few sample code. That will help you up and running in no time. Also check out this Facebook [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/) and [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/)

Comment: It look help-full let me check this.